# Custom control not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, custom-controls

I have created a simple custom control to imitate Modern UI Tiles. The project builds without any problem, but the custom control doesn't show up on the window at all. It is pretty simple, and even though I have been looking at it for a long time, I can't see what the problem can be.

Here are the files:

```
Tile.cs

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

public class Tile : ButtonBase
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof (Image), typeof (Tile), new PropertyMetadata(default(Image)));

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return (Image) GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    static Tile()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Tile), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Tile)));
    }
}
```

---

```
Themes\Generic.xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCustomControls">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TileBackgroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TileBorderBrush" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TileForegroundBrush" Color="White"/>

    <Style x:Key="TileStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:Tile}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TileBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TileBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Tile}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Image}" Margin="15,15,15,45" />
                    </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TileForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What could be the problem?

**Edit:** Here's the `Window` that I'm using it in:

```
<Window x:Class="ControlsDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MyCustomControls;assembly=MyCustomControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <customControls:Tile Content="Demo">
            <customControls:Tile.Image>
                <Image Source="Demo.png"></Image>
            </customControls:Tile.Image>
        </customControls:Tile>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where are you using this?? post the Window's XAML.

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: Sounds like your Generic.XAML is not being loaded. Use Snoop to inspect the Visual Tree at runtime.

Comment: Usually you would use a property with type `ImageSource` and put the `Image` in the template instead. Handing around actual controls is bad style.

Comment: Why would that happen?

Comment: @H.B. Thanks for the suggestion, I can change it later on. As soon as I can get this to work.

Comment: @HighCore, it seems that you are correct. Snoop doesn't show anything under `Tile`. What could be the reason?

Comment: @hattenn I have no idea dude. I don't use the Generic.XAML kind of stuff regularly.

Comment: @HighCore, got it and added an answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the problem was that Expression Blend automatically defined a style key:

```
<Style x:Key="TileStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:Tile}">
```

It works fine now after I deleted it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Tile}">
```